# How to insert values a table that affect another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
Merchandise 
(ID_MERCH char(20) PK, 
 ITEM_NAME varchar(225), 
 ID_ARTIST char(20), 
 STOCK int, 
 PRICE float
);

Merchandise_Sales 
(ID_MERCH char(20), 
 ID_ARTIST char(20), 
 QUANTITY_SOLD int, 
 ID_DIST char(10)
);

Merch_Stock 
(ID_MERCH char(20), 
 STOCK int, 
 TOTAL_SOLD decimal(32,0),
 CURRENT_STOCK decimal(33,0)
);
```

Merchandise is the information about the item including its price and overall stock.

Merchandise_Sales are like recordings of orders logged with different distributors.

Merchandise_Stock we made with a function and join but realise now we need to probably get this function saved as a procedure.

The code for Merch_Stock is:

```
CREATE TABLE MERCH_STOCK AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT MS.ID_MERCH, M.STOCK, sum(QUANTITY_SOLD) AS TOTAL_SOLD, M.STOCK-(sum(QUANTITY_SOLD)) AS CURRENT_STOCK
    FROM MERCHANDISE_SALES MS 
 INNER JOIN MERCHANDISE M ON M.ID_MERCH=MS.ID_MERCH 
 GROUP BY ID_MERCH
 );
```

What I'm thinking I need to do is a two(?) step procedure?

1a)  Updates from merchandise_sales to affect merch_stock table by using the function/code we made the table with?

1b) On merch_stock if total_sold > stock then rollback transaction OR set trigger before insertion?

2. A procedure to link stock on merchandise table and merch_stock table?

I'm not sure if these things are possible as of yet, so if anyone could help out that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I think this is related only to mysql.

Comment: use triggers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this :

```
delimiter |
    CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_in_Merchandise_Sales  BEFORE INSERT ON Merchandise_Sales FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE v_total_stock int default 0;
    DECLARE v_total_sold int default 0;
    -- get total quantity of marchandise 
    SELECT  sum(STOCK) into v_total_stock from Merchandise where ID_MERCH =new.ID_MERCH ;
    SELECT  sum(QUANTITY_SOLD )into v_total_solde from Merchandise_Sales where ID_MERCH =new.ID_MERCH ;
    
        IF(v_total_solde + new.QUANTITY_SOLD > v_total_stock) THEN 
        -- rollback
            rollback;
        END IF;
    END|
    
    DELIMITER |
```

Comment: OMG, thank you very much! 
that makes sense for me, I just got this error and have no idea what get wrong Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.